# AngularJS and CoffeeScript issue

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

So I am new to both AngularJS and CoffeeScript. I am trying out some simple examples and the one that I am trying to do is to display the count of number of checkboxes selected

and here is the Javascript for that

```
$scope.$watch('results', function(results){
$scope.count = 0;
angular.forEach(results, function(result){
  if(result.selected){
    $scope.count += 1;
  }
})
}, true);
```

This works perfectly fine. Now I am trying to do the same thing in coffeescript and here is what I have

```
$scope.$watch 'results', (results) ->
  $scope.count = 0;
  ( $scope.count += 1 if result.selected ) for result in $scope.results
```

There are no compilation errors in the above coffeescript but nothing happens when I select or deselect the checkboxes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `for in` syntax is correct but you forgot the 3rd argument:

```
$scope.$watch 'results', (results) ->
  $scope.count = 0;
  ( $scope.count += 1 if result.selected ) for result in $scope.results
, true
```

Look how I pass to `$watch` a third argument `true`. It makes a deep check of the collection values instead of just checking reference equality.

---

If you only need a shallow watch you should use $watchCollection (angular >=1.2):

```
$scope.$watchCollection 'results', (results) ->
  $scope.count = 0;
  ( $scope.count += 1 if result.selected ) for result in $scope.results
```

---

This one is compiled 100% exactly to the javascript snippet you provided:

```
$scope.$watch "results", (results) ->
  $scope.count = 0
  angular.forEach results, (result) ->
    $scope.count += 1  if result.selected
    return
  return
, true
```

I use `return` explicitly if I don't need to return anything
Check this: [Is there any way to not return something using CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391493/is-there-any-way-to-not-return-something-using-coffeescript)

Answer (score 0):

This is the compiled coffeescript:

```
$scope.$watch('results', function(results) {
  var result, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
  $scope.count = 0;
  _ref = $scope.results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    result = _ref[_i];
    _results.push(result.selected ? $scope.count += 1 : void 0);
  }
  return _results;
});
```

Which is not the same functionality as the JavaScript example you have above.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) for converting javascript to coffeescript and vice versa.
This is the result, which I believe it should do what you want:

```
$scope.$watch "results", ((results) ->
  $scope.count = 0
  angular.forEach results, (result) ->
    $scope.count += 1  if result.selected
), true
```