# Unwanted js code added while compiling coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am new to coffeescript and I have a coffee script code as

```
getProviderListDisplayValues:(domainId) ->      
    displayValues = []
    $.ajax 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "/Services/ListProviders?domainid=#{domainId}",
        success: (data) ->          
            for oneResponse in data
                displayValues.push oneResponse.name     
    displayValues
```

which is compiled to

```
CounselorHome.prototype.getProviderListValues = function(domainId) {
   var values;
   values = [];
   $.ajax({
     contentType: 'application/json',
     url: "/Services/ListProviders?domainid=" + domainId,
     success: function(data) {
       var oneResponse, _i, _len, _results;
       _results = [];
       for (_i = 0, _len = data.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
         oneResponse = data[_i];
         _results.push(values.push(oneResponse.id));
       }
       return _results;
     }
   });
   return values;
};
```

I just want to push values to `values[]` & `displayValues[]` but why is the `_results[]` array created? Does it hampers the browser efficiency? Is there any way removing such unnessary code? May be, by editing my coffee script.

**EDIT : WORKING CONDITION**

But when I put an alerting code as

```
 $.ajax 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "/Services/ListProviders?domainid=#{domainId}",
        success: (data) ->          
            for oneResponse in data
                displayValues.push oneResponse.name     
 alert displayValues
 displayValues
```

This code works and I can retrieve the required data.

Comment: _ajax_ is _asynchronous_ so I think you're trying to do something that won't work as you expect. It looks like coffee notices this, and so never gives you `_results` in a referencable way

Comment: Yes, while reurning values[] it returns undefined for Google Chrome and null for FireFox. But I have written code to push all data to values[]. Hence, the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from that [your code wouldn't work anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572), the `_results` are generated because of coffeescripts implicit function return values - and [loops are only expressions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) as well that generate arrays. The docs state:

> Sometimes functions end with loops that are intended to run only for their side-effects. Be careful that you're not accidentally returning
>   the results of the comprehension in these cases, by adding a
>   meaningful return value — like `true` — or `null`, to the bottom of
>   your  function.

So the javascript that you expected can be created by writing

```
…
    success: (data) ->
        for oneResponse in data
            displayValues.push oneResponse.name
        return
…
```

("*Trailing `return` and `return undefined` are now optimized away.*" - since version 1.0.1);
See also [Is there any way to not return something using CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7391493/1048572)

However, what you actually want is this:

```
getProviderListDisplayValues:(domainId) ->
    $.ajax
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "/Services/ListProviders?domainid=#{domainId}"
    .then (data) ->          
        for oneResponse in data
            oneResponse.name

…

getProviderListDisplayValues(…).then (displayValues) ->
    …
```

Comment: I was a bit less strong with the _won't work as expected_ rather than _wouldn't work anyway_, because OP's code doesn't actually destroy the reference to `displayValues` (until it's converted), meaning that after _success_, it should be populated. It's just there is nothing letting the rest of the script know the success function has completed ... and coffee's conversion.

Comment: @PaulS.: Yeah, and that makes the `displayValues` array unusable - I was so bold because I expected the OP to use the array just after it was returned. The mistake is just too common :-/

Comment: If so, how to populate values[], because I need to return an array?

Comment: You can't return an array which you are getting asynchronously from your function. That's just impossible (and using `alert` like in your edit only does some weird timing things that you don't want). The function in my answer does return a promise for the array. See the question I linked for further details.