# Is there a more concise Coffeescript idiom for this?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, idioms

I'm trying to translate this Javascript code:

```
if(error) {
    foo();
    return null;
}
bar()
```

into Coffeescript code, where here `bar()` is another long piece of code which I don't want to indent more

Is there a better way than this?

```
if error
    foo()
    return null
bar()
```

Comment: Maybe you can show more of the function? I suspect it's a node callback, and for that there a many patterns to simplify.

Comment: yes, it's the first snippet of a Node callback, but how does it change the question? I'm asking for a general approach.
Otherwise, what would you suggest?

Comment: @mattecapu What better way you are expecting?

Comment: @mattecapu: I would suggest to use promises. Or, depending on what `foo` is, some generic higher-order wrapper around the callback.

Comment: Sure, that's a viable option, but being new to coffeescript I wanted to see how to manipulate such expressions. Apart from this, I'm going to use promises anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine for me.

Though, if you really want it to be a one-liner, you could take advantage of parentheses:

```
return (foo(); null) if error
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. However maybe is too much concise? Do you think it's less readable?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if error
    foo()
else
    bar()
```

(possibly [with a trailing `return`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7391493/1048572))

Comment: check the edited answer, here `bar()` is really a bigger piece of code

Comment: Then there's not really anything more concise (altough I don't see what's wrong with indenting `bar`)

Answer (score -1):

You could rewrite it in an alternate form (slightly different symatically, since you're returning the result of foo()):

```
return foo() if error
```