# avoiding auto generated returns in coffee script

Tags: javascript, hash, coffeescript, passwords

How can I get rid of the auto generated returns in my coffee script:

```
createHash = (password) ->
  bcrypt.genSalt 10, (err, salt) ->
    bcrypt.hash password, salt, (err, hash) ->
      hash
```

I'm getting ...

```
createHash = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    return bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      return hash;
    });
  });
};
```

... but I desire a solution without the returns:

```
createHash = function(password) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      return hash;
    });
  });
};
```

How am I getting this done?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7391493/660921

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, CoffeeScript functions return the value of their last expression so this:

```
f = ->
    # Bunch of interesting things...
    6
```

is equivalent to:

```
f = ->
    # Bunch of interesting things...
    return 6
```

hence the `return`s appearing in the transpiled JavaScript.

In JavaScript, a function without an explicit `return` implicitly returns `undefined` so these return the same thing:

```
function() { }
function() { return }
function() { return undefined }
```

Putting those two things together gives you two options:

1. Throw an `undefined` at the bottom of your function to bypass the implicit `return` with an explicit one:

   ```
   createHash = (password) ->
     bcrypt.genSalt 10, (err, salt) ->
       bcrypt.hash password, salt, (err, hash) ->
         hash
       undefined
     undefined
   ```
2. Or better, explicitly indicate that you're returning nothing with an empty `return`:

   ```
   createHash = (password) ->
     bcrypt.genSalt 10, (err, salt) ->
       bcrypt.hash password, salt, (err, hash) ->
         hash
       return
     return
   ```

The second option should give you exactly the JavaScript you're looking for:

```
var createHash;
createHash = function(password) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      return hash;
    });
  });
};
```